# Microsoft Graph: Get user calendar event with beta version

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, beta

I´m trying to get an user calendar event with Microsoft Graph beta versión. 
I can get calendar info with this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user}/calendars/{calendarid}
```

Then I try to access to specific event through this request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user}/calendars/{calendarid}/events/{eventId}
```

But I get this error code:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NavigationNotSupported",
        "message": "Recursive navigation is not allowed after property 'Events' according to the entity schema.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2c73c51d-05b0-4499-9420-9247f4c8c576",
            "date": "2018-05-23T15:16:44"
        }
    }
}
```

Both requests works with Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The way to get an event (regardless of which calendar it is in) once you have the `id` is like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user}/events/{eventId}
```