# Unable to update event Beta endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have created an app with all the needed permissions.

I can create an event using beta endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xyz@test.com/calendars/XXX/events/YYY
```

But I'm getting an error when I attempt to update it:

```
{
  "code": "NavigationNotSupported",
  "message": "Recursive navigation is not allowed after property 'Events' according to the entity schema.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "9dd2afea-219a-436d-bd27-e73a7407dfab",
    "date": "2019-09-27T07:49:35"
  }
}
```

Also, I can however update this event using the v1.0 endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xyz@test.com/calendars/XXX/events/YYY
```

Is there is an issue in the Microsoft Graph beta or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. without seeing the actual request you're submitting, its really hard to diagnose what is happening. Error messages and URIs alone are not very helpful.

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the answer that helps you(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in), this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

We should use **/v1.0** version instead of **/beta** version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer in this SO question,
[Microsoft Graph: Get user calendar event with beta version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492177/microsoft-graph-get-user-calendar-event-with-beta-version)

You should probably have some luck updating the event with this URL without having to navigate through the "calendars" navigation property as follows.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xyz@test.com/events/YYY
```